# Jackson annotation of array element labelled

Tags: json, jackson

I have a Json like this:

```
"messages":[{
    "message": {
        "id":"198", 
        "subject":"No more beer", 
        "text":"Bring more" 
    },
    "message": { 
        "id":"199", 
        "subject":"it rains", 
        "text":"I don't have umbrella" 
    } 
}]
```

How can I annotate this?

thx
Zamek

Answer (score 0):

I can find the solution:

```
class Messages {
    @JsonProperty("messages")
    List<MessageWrapper> messages;
}

class MessageWrapper {
   @JsonProperty("message")
   Message message;
}

class Message {
   @JsonProperty("id")
   int id;
   @JsonProperty("subject")
   String subject;
   @JsonProperty("text")
   String text;
}
```

the usage is a little bit weird:

```
List<MessageWrapper> msgs;
int id = msg.getMessage().getId();
```